# How to fix changed source lines showing ^M with "git diff" but look fine with vim/gedit/cat -e?

Tags: linux, git, vim, carriage-return

I have searched high and low for anyone asking a similar question.  It does *not* seem to be a simple case of `:set fileformat=dos` or `:set fileformat=unix`.

Writing the file out with `:set fileencoding=latin1` and `:set fileformat=dos` changed such that `git diff` reports all the lines to have ^M appended.

The code was originally happily existing as:

```
...
if (v == value32S)
{
...
```

I made the outrageously radical improvement to (which looks fine on the screen in vim):

```
...
if (v == value32S ||
    v == value33)
{
...
```

But `git diff` to check for erroneous changes shows:

```
diff --git a/csettings.cpp b/csettings.cpp
index 1234..8901 100755
--- a/csettings.cpp
+++ b/csettings.cpp
@@ -2466,7 +2466,8 @@ bool MyClass::settingIsValid(QString s)

#if CONFIG_1 || CONFIG_2

-       if (v == value32S)
+       if (v == value32S ||^M
+           v == value33)^M
        {
              doSomething(new_v);
```

where the bold italic text is reverse video.

I have tried several means to make the apparently spurious carriage returns *go away*.  First was to be sure there wasn't a hidden character.   View with `vim`  `:set list`:

```
...
if (v == value32S ||$
    v == value33)$
{$
...
```

Seems fine.  Dumping the file (microdetails vary to protect NDA, and I am too lazy to make it a perfect deception):

```
$ hd csettings.cpp
(...)
0000eae0 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx  xx 65 33 32 53 20 7c 7c  |(v == value32S |||
0000eaf0 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 76 20  |..             v |
0000eb00 3d 3a 20 xx xx xx xx xx  xx 65 33 33 29 0d 0a 20  |== ...value33).. |
```

*All* of the other lines also end in "0d 0a", so this looks fine.  An interesting suggestion was to use `cat -e` (which was new to me):

```
$ cat -e c.cpp

...
if (v == value32S ||^M$
    v == value33)^M$
{^M$
...
```

Another suggestion was to use `file` for clues:

```
$ file csettings.cpp
csettings.cpp:  C source, UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Interestingly, this is the only file in this directory (of header files and cpp code) which isn't `ASCII text`.  Some files have CRLF line terminators and some do not.  Also, some show `C++ source` and others are `C source` which I assume isn't significant.

Deleting the file and `git checkout` to get a fresh copy also shows it as UTF-8, which I traced to having the degree symbol in some strings ("°F" and "°C") so UTF-8 doesn't seem to be an issue.

Still, I don't see why using `vim` to edit *only these lines* would cause this problem.  Or maybe it isn't a problem?  Any ideas?

----- Addendum -----

`git config --get-regexp core.*` shows

```
core.repositoryformatversion 0
core.filemode true
core.bare false
core.logallrefupdates true
```

Comment: Your hex-dump does **not** look fine, you have `0d 0a` sequences in there. And you caused those yourself by setting  `:set fileformat=dos` ...

Comment: @tink:  Starting with a fresh copy (from the repository), I don't do any `:set` commands.  It shows `"csettings.cpp" [dos] 3725L, 117823C` on the status line before making any changes.

Comment: If you have `fileformats` set to include `dos`, vim will figure out that the file has CRLF line endings, *remove* the CRLFs while you edit, then *put them back* when you save. I use `set ffs=unix` in my vimrc to totally the magic, which is a bit crude, but effective.

Comment: @torek:  My default setting is `fileformats=unix,dos`.  When you exit, do you do anything special?

Comment: No, I don't have to—`fileformats` are the ones vim accepts (ie detects automatically), and `fileformat` is the current mode. When the latter is `dos` vim adds the CRs back, when it's `unix` it doesn't. So by limiting `fileformats` to `unix` I never have them stripped and never add them.

Comment: I have a feeling this may be related to your core.whitespace settings in git.  What happens if you set core.whitespace to include "cr-at-eol"?  I think vim is doing the right thing here... you're editing a dos formatted file and it's treating it as a dos formatted file.  I suspect git is just highlighting what it thinks is a whitespace error.

Comment: @RandyMorris:  Check my addendum to the question.  Are the defaults a problem?  If I add a `core.whitespace` setting, will that mess up the repository?

Comment: @wallyk The answer that was added by Brian below explains this in greater detail.  I'm quite sure this is going to solve your issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Git assumes that you're using Unix line endings in the repository and highlights carriage returns as trailing whitespace. However, by default, it highlights trailing whitespace only on new lines, since the goal is to avoid introducing *new* problems.

If you run `git diff --ws-error-highlight=all`, you'll see that there are also carriage returns on the lines being removed and on the context lines. If you don't want to see this, you can set `core.whitespace` to `cr-at-eol`, which will prevent it from being highlighted. There are no ill effects to this; it simply prevents carriage returns from being treated as trailing whitespace.

If you're planning on using this project on non-Windows systems, you should convert the line endings to Unix and use a `.gitattributes` file to specify the `text` attribute for text files so the line ending is automatically converted based on the operating system in use. This may be valuable even if your project is only used on Windows, since if someone has `core.autocrlf` set, you may end up with mixed line endings.

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  I will give it a go in the morning.  The code base was managed with SVN on Windows originally even though it always targeted Linux.  Sometime in the last few years it was moved to git on Linux.

Comment: Thanks!  This does indeed fix the problem.  For thoroughness for other being abused by this issue, the command to change this in the affected repository is `git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol` when the current working directory is somewhere within the repository.

Comment: I noticed this today, and this is an excellent explanation.  This behavior confusingly makes it look as if you're adding a carriage return, even when in fact it was already there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using unix based Operating System.
Normally using vi or cat command, ^M characters are not visible. 
You can see using cat -v command.
Eg. 
cat -v < file_name >

To get rid of these characters use dos2unix command.
Eg. 
dos2unix < file_name >

This will remove those ^M characters and save the result in same file itself. So you don't have to create any temp file for storing intermediate file content.

Comment: That would be nice, however there are over 500,000 source files in this project. Most of them use "dos" format line endings.  Changing all of them is not an option.  Even changing just this file would introduce thousands of "different" lines and greatly complicates comparing actual content changes between before the conversion and afterward.